# Apache SSL Offloading/Reverse Proxy for Websockets. (Spring App)

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, proxy

I have a Java Spring application running on a Tomcat Server. I use an Apache server for SSL offloading.

```
<VirtualHost *:8043>
    ServerName myserver.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "pathtokeystore.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "pathtoserver.key"

    ProxyRequests On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPassMatch      ^/(MyApp/.*)$ http://App:8080/$1
    ProxyPassReverse    /MyApp http://App:8080/Home
    //not including other stuff below
```

This works, and i can make a https request to the apache server on port 8043 and the request is forwarded to the tomcat server as a http request. Correct me if my understanding is wrong, but i believe thats how its working.

My app has a Websocket endpoint. (I use Spring/Stomp/ActiveMQ). Currently the endpoint url is i.e: ws://appname:61614.
I can connect directly to the websocket endpoint but this is insecure and i would like to change this to wss://appname:61614 and have requests made through the apache server to wss://myapp:61614, which will handle SSL and then forward them to ws://app:61614.

Is it possible to achieve this in the same way it can be done with https and http? So could i have something like this:

```
//Loadmodule mod_proxy_wstunnel at the start of httpd conf file

    <VirtualHost *:61615>
        ServerName myserver.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "pathtokeystore.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "pathtoserver.key"

        ProxyPassMatch      / ws://app:61614
        ProxyPassReverse    / ws://app:61614
```

Am i correct in thinking all wss requests i make to port 61615 of the apache server will be forwarded to ws://app:61614 of my tomcat app? And this will work? Can Apache handle websockets proxying in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

ProxyPassMatch requires regex and some sort of treatment at the target. ProxyPassMatch      / ws://app:61614 looks very incorrect to me. Also match ending slashes.

Try and let us know:

```
ProxyPass / ws://app:61614/
ProxyPassReverse / ws://app:61614/
```